# Is it possible to make a tween for a node selected by name?

Tags: kineticjs

I want to make a tween which runs when a polygon is hovered. I when the mouse enters the polygon I get it's name, and I want to run the animation for that very polygon. I want to animate the fill, want to go opaque from white.

```
var polly = layer.find('Polygon');

polly.on('mouseover', function() {
    var name=this.attrs.name;
    thiz=layer.find('.'+name);
    tween.play();
});


  var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
   // node: Polygon,
    name: thiz,
    duration: 2,
    scaleX: 1.3,
    scaleY: 1.3,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,0)
  });
```

is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tween from one color to another color, you can do that by tweening each of the r,g,b components separately:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/zsPSW/

```
poly.hoverTween=new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: poly,
    duration: 0.50,
    scaleX: 1.3,
    scaleY: 1.3,
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear,
    fillR: 255,
    fillG: 255,
    fillB: 255,
});
```

But...

"Transparent" is not a color, so you can't tween from transparent (a non-color) to white.

As a workaround...

For each poly:

- Create a group.
- Add a version of the poly that only has a white fill with opacity of 0.00 (no stroke).
- Add a version of the poly that only has a stroke.

Then you can tween the opacity of the white-fill-poly from 0.00 to 1.00 on mouseover.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks that is a good idea!

But I still have to tween by name, and not by node.

Comment: There isn't a .setNode(polygon1) method on Kinetic.Tween.  The workarounds are (1) Add a tween to each polygon you create so when you identify the polygon you can call the hover-tween method on that specific polygon, or (2) Have a function that takes in a polygon object and builds a tween for it on-the=fly.  My answer takes the first approach.  Cheers!